# Using grep to select strings contained in a list

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
id  <- c(1:5)
name <- c("blackdog","whitedog", "blackcat","whitecat","greyrabbit")
df <- data.frame(id,name)
df
```

I also have a list for selection:

```
select <- c("black","dog","grey")
```

So I want to return a dataframe containing:
blackdog, blackcat,whitedog,greyrabbit

I have tried:

```
dfselect <-df[grep(select,df[,2]),]
dfselect
```

but this is only selecting the first element of the list.

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a loop here:

```
df[grep(paste(select,collapse='|'),df$name),]

## id       name
## 1  1   blackdog
## 2  2   whitedog
## 3  3   blackcat
## 5  5 greyrabbit
```

Comment: +1 - My first thought was to insert "|" in the list but I couldn't get it to work easily. What I missed was "collapse". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is use the apply functions:

```
> df$name[unique(unlist(lapply(select, FUN=function(x) grep(x,df$name))))]
[1] blackdog   blackcat   whitedog   greyrabbit
Levels: blackcat blackdog greyrabbit whitecat whitedog
```

Is that what you were after?